# How can I create a insert/update form for multiple table in Oracle Apex 5.1.4

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have craeted two tables. I have also created a page and shown all data as classic report by inner joining between two tables.  Now I want to know how can I create a form to update both table at a time? 
For single table it can be done easily by creating form and report page. But In case of multiple table what will be way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create new page by the new page creation wizard using the Form > Single Page Master Detail template. 
It will guide you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option: create a view, then create instead-of trigger(s) upon that view. Use the same view as a data source on the Apex page.

I know for sure that it works in Oracle Forms; never tried it in Apex, though, but I believe that it should be just fine.